# Adding an item to a databound combobox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Am trying to add an item to databound combobox.
I tried this but it doesnt work:
     `ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0, New Object() {"undefined"})`
Is it possible any way

Comment: what about adding the new item into the combobox datasource and rebind again?

Comment: @Nick i added an entry to the database, named it undefined, when the user selects it, the row.address is set to DBNull that way, its no more a foreign key in the row, and an item is displayed in the combo box in case the address is not known. feeling stupid but victorious :-)

Comment: It's one of the solution, but I will do it in the query instead
`SELECT 0 AS iKey, 'undefined' AS sDesc UNION SELECT PKey, Description FROM Table1`. In this case you don't need to have a dummy data in your database

Comment: that's something to be accounted for, ille implement this as soon as possible. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");